# .Xlsm to .Pdf Macro damaging the .pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, macros

I have modified the below macro I found to take files from Folder A and place them in Folder B with .pdf as the file extension:

```
Sub Xlsm_to_Pdf()

 Dim Xlsmfolder As String
 Dim PdfFolder As String
 Dim fname As String
 Dim wBook As Workbook

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 Xlsmfolder = "\\Desktop\Macro Testing\TestFolderA\"
 PdfFolder = "\\Desktop\Macro Testing\TestFolderB\"

 fname = Dir(Xlsmfolder & "*.xlsm")

 Do While fname <> ""
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Xlsmfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
    wBook.SaveAs PdfFolder & Replace(fname, ".xlsm", ".pdf"), ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    wBook.Close False
 fname = Dir
 Loop

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The macro executes as expected and the files from Folder A are moved to Folder B with the .pdf extension. My issue is the files become damaged. How are the files becoming damaged and is the macro driving this issue?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like the files are saved as `*.xlsm` again, and only the name is changed to `*.pdf` due to `ThisWorkbook.FileFormat` which does not change until it is saved... but I may be wrong here

Comment: How do you know the file got damaged?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, but I can navigate to the new location of the files as .pdf and they are unable to be opened. I then receive the message saying the files have been damaged.

Comment: I agree Dirk Reichel- it seems as though the above macro is only changing the name, not the actual file (somehow). I posted a similar question yesterday named  "How to copy multiple files at once from one folder to another while also giving a new file extension [on hold]. In that post, there is similar Macro that I had found which will successfully open a .Xlsm file and convert to .Pdf. I am able to open the .Pdf in result of that macro running. If I can combine that macro with this macro to convert about one hundred .Xlsm files, that would be fantastic

Comment: You should probably include in this question the original script from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36843898/4453460); the file saving part is quite different, as it uses the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method.

Answer (score 0):

A few things...  First, just changing the filename extension will not magically convert the Excel files to PDF files. However, as your example code even includes a reference to the fact that the **Workbook.SaveAs** method accepts a parameter for **file format**. A search online should quickly lead you to the Microsoft provided documentation on MSDN at [this url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx). Here it details all of the parameters you can use for this method. The **FileFormat** parameter looks exactly like what you want to investigate. So if you then click on the link in the article which takes you to the corresponding **xlFileFormat** documentation on MSDN at [this url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx), you will see that there are no defined options for saving a file in PDF format using that method.

However, if it can be done in Excel and automated through VBA, then there is a trick you can use to find the right information if you are not having any luck searching online or in MSDN. Just record a Macro in Excel of you performing the one step you need help with, then stop recording and look at the code Excel generated and put into the Macro. Using this technique, you should quickly realize that the method you are searching for is called **Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat** and is documented on MSDN at [this url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, dmarietta. I am relatively familiar with recording Macro's and then looking at the generated code. I was under the impression that navigating outside of the active workbook to try moving files from one folder to another would not have been feasible through recording. In terms of syntax and parameters, I am a beginner and partially follow what you are saying. If I incorporated Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat into my code, can it be written to select all files in a folder and then convert to pdf in the new folder? or does Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat only work within a single file?

Comment: Yes, it only works on a single file at a time. So in your example code, you should be able to replace the call to the wBook.SaveAs  method with the appropriate wBook.ExportAsFixedFormat call.